# Ajax erroneously succeeding to GET from incorrect URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project that needs to determine whether a URL is reachable. For this, I'm trying to use an ajax GET.

To test, I have this:

```
var MY_URL = "";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: MY_URL,
    complete: function(xhr, statusTest) {
        alert("MY_URL is " + MY_URL);
        alert("xhr.status is " + xhr.status);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Sad day: " + e);
    }
});
```

I expect to see `Sad day: SOME_ERROR_MESSAGE_HERE`, but instead, I'm seeing `MY_URL is` followed by `xhr.status is 200`.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Thanks,
erip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser interprets an empty string as a relative URL, which ends up sending a request to your page URL.